# Remotely create network shares

Tags: .net, security, networking

I am trying to figure out how to accomplish the following task:

1. Create a network share on a remote
   computer using .NET
2. The target computer is
   on the same network.
3. The target computer's
   admin username and password are
   known.

Your thoughts?  How would you go about to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best and easiest method to do Windows Administrative tasks from code is through [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582(VS.85).aspx). Almost anything can be done on a Windows machine, local or remote, through WMI.

In order to administer a Windows shared folder you will need to interact with the [`Win32_Share`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394435(VS.85).aspx) WMI class.

Sample on how to use WMI to create a shared folder:

```
    ManagementPath path = new ManagementPath("Win32_Share");
    path.Server = ".";              // Change this to your server

    object[] parameters = new object[] {
        "C:\\TestShare",            // Path to shared folder
        "Test Share",               // Share name
        0x0,                        // Share type (disk drive)
        5,                          // Maximum amount of concurrent users
        null,                       // Password (optional)
        null                        // Security level (optional)
    };

    ManagementClass share = new ManagementClass(path);
    object result = share.InvokeMethod("Create", parameters);
```

You will need to add a reference to the `System.Management` assembly in order to access the WMI classes. You'll also need access to the remote machine of course.

Check out the [WMI Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394572(VS.85).aspx) for more details. Specifically check out the [Win32_Share Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394435(VS.85).aspx) reference on what all the parameters and return codes mean.

Comment: The sample code here will not work in the server is remote. If server is remote:- remove "path.Server = ".";" and add "path.Path = "\\\\ServerName\\ROOT\\cimv2:Win32_Share";"

Answer (score 0):

http://www.google.ca/search?hl=en&q=create+share+net suggests that you'll be using PInvoke to invoke the `NetShareAdd` API.

I was wondering whether an alternative might be to invoke the `NET SHARE` command-line command, however looking at `NET HELP SHARE` I don't see how to use it to create a share on a remote computer.